# Работа с DOM jq/js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, dom

На сайте есть вертикальная карусель , реализованная через плагин Fullpage.js , цветовые тона сайта предполагают , что основное меню меняется при скролле , это легко было реализовать когда ещё не было идеи  с fullpage.js , теперь как я понимаю,  функция `$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 700) {

```
                    $('.header').addClass('black_menu');
                    $('.menu-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
                    $('.main__menu-black').removeClass('d-none');
                    $('.main__menu').removeClass('justify-content-between');
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass('black_menu');
            $('.menu-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
            $('.main__menu-black').addClass('d-none');
            $('.main__menu').addClass('justify-content-between');
        }
    });`
```

не имеет смысла тк страница не скроллица , теперь нужно , как я правильно понимаю, отслеживать изменения тега body на наличие определенного класса с которого и меню меняется ps. пробовал метод .hasClass() , но изменения должны отслеживаться параллельно, а не сразу как страница загрузилась , пробовал ещё всё в цикл , но тоже что-то не вышло , как подобное реализуется ?

Comment: Маловато данных. Добавь сюда ещё и код html одного из блоков, чтобы было понятно, с какими классами работать.

Comment: Можно через setInterval() проверять появился клас новый или нет